# Form fields getting cleared off of user inputs after validation errors

Tags: 6, ubercart

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/hook-validate-returns-errors-but-the-form-has-lost-all-the-users-submitted-v) is almost exactly my problem, but I'm not making the mistake made by that poster. As in, I'm not using #value to populate my fields, but the proper #default-value.

I'm working with ubercart, and the form I made is part of a checkout pane. Unfortunately, I have had to use drupal_get_form() within the main uc-cart-checkout-form as the value of a checkout pane. Otherwise, I cannot provide independent submit buttons or clump them together properly.

The problem is that after validation, the form fields are getting cleared out. Only the default values are being reset. I have tried writing a validation handler (even if actually the validation is taking place in a custom validation function that I'm calling from the hook_form_alter() of uc_cart_checkout_form)

Is doing this manually with SESSIONS the only way out? By calling a drupal_get_form inside a drupal_get_form, am I confusing FAPI irrevocably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon using the ternary conditional operator to check if there is anything in $form_state['values'] would get there, i.e. something like:

```
$default_value = 'Test Default Value';

$form['test'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => !empty($form_state['values']['test'])?$form_state['values']['test']:$default_value,
);
```